# Help with computing a differential form.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

My question is rather straightforward.

Let $d \geq 3$, then given the following parametrization
$$ z_i = a_i/|a|,\ i=1,2,...,d-1 $$ where $|a|^2 =1+ \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} a_i^2$. 
What is
$$
d z_1 \wedge d z_2 \wedge ... \wedge d z_{d-1} =?
$$

Computing the differential for $d=3,4$ one would expect that the following is true for general $d$ ( if my calculations are correct): 
$$
d z_1 \wedge d z_2 \wedge ... \wedge d z_{d-1} = \frac{1}{|a|^{d+1}} da_1 \wedge da_2 \wedge ... \wedge d a_{d-1},
$$
however proving that this holds in generality seems to elude me. So far I've attempted to do induction on $d$ as well as trying to derive some general expression for 
$$
d z_1 \wedge ... \wedge d z_k,\ 1 \leq k \leq d-1, 
$$
but I seem to fail to obtain anything useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by applying the Matrix determinant lemma:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma, 
and recognizing that the Jacobian is given by $J_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|a|} - \frac{a_i a_j}{|a|^3}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.